# How can I POS tag German texts?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I've been doing some natural language processing work.

For English POS tagging, it's rather simple because I only need to use built-in nltk functions. I want to process German texts similarly.

Since nltk doesn't have a built-in function for German, I've tried using Stanford POSTagger:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
import os
import nltk
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
sentence = "Man könnte Klöckner vorhalten, sich an ihre eigenen Appelle nicht zu halten. Doch niemand in der Union wagte das. Nicht einmal die von ihr attackierten Briefschreiber. Klöckner genießt im Moment Narrenfreiheit."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence, 'german')
german_postagger1 = StanfordPOSTagger(r'E:/python/nlptest/models/german-hgc.tagger', r'E:/python/nlptest/stanford-postagger.jar')
gp1 = german_postagger1.tag(tokens)
```

It takes almost 7 seconds to finish processing, which is unbearable for me.

I also tried the module [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-de), but it doesn't support Python 3 and I'm using Python 3.4.

Is there an alternative and faster way to POS tag German sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TreeTagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) is a fast easy-to-install well-documented decison-tree based tagger with support for many languages (and yeah, it's built by a German) and a [python wrapper](https://perso.limsi.fr/pointal/doku.php?id=dev:treetaggerwrapper).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Shameless plug

Try installing the full `nltk_cli` (https://github.com/alvations/nltk_cli) and use this command:

```
alvas@ubi:~/git/nltk_cli$ echo "Man könnte Klöckner vorhalten, sich an ihre eigenen Appelle nicht zu halten. Doch niemand in der Union wagte das. Nicht einmal die von ihr attackierten Briefschreiber. Klöckner genießt im Moment Narrenfreiheit." > test.in

alvas@ubi:~/git/nltk_cli$ python3 stanford.py --tool=postagger \
> --jar=$HOME/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar \
> --model=$HOME/stanford-postagger/models/german-fast.tagger \
> --input=test.in
```

[out]:

```
Man#PIS könnte#VMFIN Klöckner#NE vorhalten,#VVFIN sich#PRF an#APPR ihre#PPOSAT eigenen#ADJA Appelle#NN nicht#PTKNEG zu#APPR halten.#ADJA Doch#KON niemand#PIS in#APPR der#ART Union#NN wagte#VVFIN das.#ADV Nicht#PTKNEG einmal#ADV die#ART von#APPR ihr#PPOSAT attackierten#ADJA Briefschreiber.#NN Klöckner#NE genießt#VVFIN im#APPRART Moment#NN Narrenfreiheit.#NE
```

Comment: Shameless plug? :) Cool tool.

Comment: @erip Whoops forgot to add that. Updated answer =)

Answer (score 0):

The fast rule-based POS and morphological tagger [RDRPOSTagger](http://rdrpostagger.sourceforge.net/) supports pre-trained models for 13 languages including German (in both POS and morphological tagging). It is implemented in Python (and aslo Java).

For example of tagging speed in English for the Python implementation, the tagging speed is 8K words/second computed for a single threaded implementation, using a computer with Core2Duo 2.4GHz. You can achieve much faster tagging speed with a more powerful computer.